# How to get rid of cockroaches using natural products?

Tags: pest-control, insect

They come from open junction box on kitchen wall, and they spotted around fridge. Recently been seeing one or two in bedrooms. I think its because I sprayed Raid in the kitchen. This been going around for a month or more now. The type looks to be german cockroaches. Where I live there arnt known brand pest control products to use, and the ones that are available dont always list their ingredients. So what natural everyday things I can find that can kill them once and for all? I put generic bait around the fridge, but I still see them now in other places. To stop them from getting into bedrooms, i spray Raid on the floor.

Comment: Boric acid, aka borax, aka orthoboric acid is safe (LD50 same as table salt) and extremely effective. It cleared out the whole apt building of a room I rented in mexico. Works on ants too.

Comment: should i mix it with anything or just put powder on the floor?

Comment: both. look up bait recipes as the mixing ratio is somewhat important for long-term eradication. You do want the powder lightly coating travel/hiding areas; under drawers/cabinets, behind the fridge, etc to kill off any newcomers after the bait kills the colony and nymphs

Comment: Check the refrigerator motor area ; I once had a "colony" living in an electric rely box near the motor. Borax works well, I put it in all my walls before the drywall was installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great luck with boric acid based products for ants and roaches and just about any bug.  It's inexpensive, effective, and relatively safe.  It's easy to dust in the cracks and crevasses and gaps and spaces where they hide.

Diatomaceous earth is another alternative that I have heard is just as safe and effective, but boric acid has worked so well I haven't bothered to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that hot sauce or anything spicy hot will deter them. There is also electronic repellants that produce radio waves on a frequency that they cannot stand that they'll run from. But make sure that it's a good brand and one that can penetrate through walls

Comment: bugs cannot sense RF any better than we can, that's snake-oil. Some sonic treatments can be useful for larger pests like rats, gophers, and pigeons, but invisible waves won't help anything, though that would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

Natural solution that helped me was spiders. They love eating them.
Aside from that, you need to find their nests which is easily identified by their droppings beneath and kill them. Typical nest locations are dark, warm areas such as near hot water pipes under the sink. Kill the eggs as well.
Good luck!